# iOS image annotation tool, to make highlight mask

Tags: ios, image-processing

Help, looking for **an iOS** way to do this:
[image: before and after-image gets highlight mask]

(highlight by using translucent mask).

I know how on a desktop... looking for mobile method.
Thought maybe the "mask image" workflow in Shortcuts would do it, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score -1):

Found one app that will do (I'm sure there are others)

Annotable

Sorry, couldn’t figure out to copy App Store link:

https://itunes.apple.com/app/annotable/id1099850421?mt=8&uo=4&at=10l4RA

[image: screenshot]

Comment: While it's great to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer), this post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed.

Comment: Yes, at least say the app's price and post a screenshot and link. Thanks!